# Generating unique numeric ids in multiple thread application without locking

Tags: java, multithreading

Multi Threaded application with n threads implemented using `ExecutorService`.

There are x (tens of millions) tasks submitted to the `ExecutorService`.

Each task needs to generate millions (number of items is not constant) of items, where each item must have a numeric **unique** id (has max length).

*How Can I generate such ids* ?

Where the restrictions are:

- No locking! No blocking! – **performance is a top priority**  (so
  can’t use Random next, AtomicInteger, or concurrent hash of ids to pull from ) .
- Id must be unique across all threads.
- Preferable to have ids to be sequential if possible but not required.
- of course no dbs and etc...

Having said that,

- It’s not possible to give each thread a “range of ids” for it to use,
  as in theory 1 thread can get 99% of tasks – so we don’t know what
  range to give it (and we can’t just give it a huge range).
- It’s not possible to create Random instance for each thread as
  uniqueness is not guaranteed.

Will appreciate you ideas.

Comment: Use process ID and thread ID as the prefix. You need to ensure that the ID field has enough precision (width in bits) to allow for adding those prefixes.

Comment: You can implement an "ID block allocation" scheme. Use AtomicInteger to allocate a block of ID, e.g. if the AtomicInteger returns 0x33 to thread T, the block of ID that thread T can use is the range 0x3300 - 0x33FF. This reduces the "intensity" of atomic operation, which also reduces the probability that a cache contention occurs as a result of that atomic operation. (Note: this probability is not linear to the intensity.)

Comment: And, when you say that "performance is a top priority", please explain your performance expectations. In other words, at what rate do you need to generate these IDs? Billions per CPU core per second?

Comment: Your requirements seem fairly extreme. How many IDs do you need per second, across your entire system? How many ns can ID generation realistically cost? In practice, an atomic int counter is likely to perform reasonably well, especially if all tasks run on the same CPU socket, especially if you're using Intel CPUs, or if only few threads are used. The next best thing is a thread-local counter where you encode the thread ID in some unused bits for uniqueness. Even for a 64 bit ID, this might leave enough bits even when all tasks are scheduled on the same thread.

Comment: Any problems with normal [Guids](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2982748/create-a-guid-in-java)?

Comment: It might also be worth pointing out that modern random number generators are extremely fast and have very good quality, unlike classic algorithms like Mersenne Twisters. A Xoshiro-based RNG can output numbers faster than you can write them to RAM (at least on desktop-class systems).

Comment: Why is it not possible for tasks to generate objects within a dedicated space? Each task has a 32bit head that is 4.2 billion tasks, and can use that as a prefix to a 128bit guid. That leaves a 96bit address space, which is quite possible overkill. If its not just double the amount of bits. Alternately flip it and have the tasks with 96bit id and a 32bit address space, if 1 task is responsible for less then 4.2 billion objects. This also makes it quite clear where the object came from. Task ids can be assigned by the threads executing them from a block.

Comment: @rwong I can't use ranges as stated in question, as I don't know how many task the thread will take (it might take 99% of tasks)

Comment: @Kain0_0, the id filed size is limited by configuration (of course it will match the max number of items to be generate)

Comment: Give each ID generator a unique ID. Give each ID generator a counter. Your ID is the concatenation of those numbers. Please explain why that is not enough.

Comment: @candied_orange,  you can't just concatenate numbers, lets sey Thread 1 gets id  347 Thread 2 get ID 3.
they both might get same id "347"+"1" and  "3" +"471"  and you can't have placeholder because the length of the id will be too big.

Comment: @Yev I believe candied_orange said concatenate,not add.  You can also put a separator in between the thread id and count (like '-') to ensure the multiple threads can't come up with the same ID.

Comment: you may not be able to ranges for the id but surely the thread id you can limit to a fixed size and then just 0 pad it - or just dont concatenate and your key is the pair of numbers

Comment: @Yev As GrandmasterB said I was not suggesting that you add them. You make a unique ID by using the two other ID's together. The database people call these a composite key. If you have a reason not to do this I'd like to hear it.

Comment: How are you going to consume the globally unique numbers you need? Do you pass all of them to storage or other threads? Only some of them? Do you verify the IDs uniqueness when you merge them from threads? Can the verification block your threads?

Comment: @max630 if the threads ID is part of the ID a simple counter on each thread keeps them unique.

Comment: @Yev You misunderstood the ID Block Allocation scheme. It is not a fixed preallocation to each thread. Instead, each block will allocate in increments of 256 IDs. They don't ask for more until their current allocation of 256 IDs are exhausted. Once a thread exhausts the block, it will perform an allocation (via AtomicInteger, locks, etc) to get a new block of 256 IDs.

Answer (score 5):

It's unclear why the standard answer, GUIDs, is inappropriate for your case. If the standard library generator is too slow for you, there are alternatives touted as being faster.

If GUIDs are too slow for you, then you need to say what performance is required and why you can't just throw more CPUs at the problem.

Secondly, you state no locking/blocking. However, for interthread communication on the same machine, where you are just grabbing large blocks of integer space for use as sequential Ids, there would be hardly any locking required and it would be super fast.

"Give me the next free block of Xmil numbers every Xmil items processed" has got to beat anything else for 'time to generate next number' and the locking interval is fully under your control.

If even that is too slow, you can get up to 4 unique sets of numbers with odd, even, negative odd and negative even. A simple short executorId in addition to your taskId expands the number of sets arbitrarily.

Answer (score 2):

You can't get *sequential* ID's across multiple threads without some form of synchronization. But if this requirement is optional, you can have a separate counter in each thread and combine it with a thread ID from a global counter. E.g. 64 bit for the thread ID combined with a 64 bit thread-specific counter into a 128 bit integer which is guaranteed to be unique across all threads. This will be *extremely* fast since you just need to increment the thread-specific counter to generate a new ID.

And of course you shouldn't *add* the thread ID and the counter, since that would lead to duplicates. Instead you use the thread ID as the upper 64 bit and the counter as the lower 64 bit of a 128 bit number.

> It’s not possible to give each thread a “range of ids” for it to use,
>   as in theory 1 thread can get 99% of tasks – so we don’t know what
>   range to give it (and we can’t just give it a huge range).

Well it is just a question of having a large enough range. With a 64 bit counter it will be able to run for hundreds of years without overflowing.

Alternatively you could use the current timestamp instead of a counter. This will be slightly slower, but probably not measurably so, and the advantage is you don't risk losing counter state e.g. in case of a restart.